# Given the following system of congruence prove the following

Tags: elementary-number-theory

g = gcd(m,n)

$$x \equiv a \pmod m$$

$$x \equiv b \pmod n$$

The solution is given by

$$x \equiv  \Bigg\{ a + \frac{(b-a)m}{g}  \Bigg[ (\frac{m}{g})^{-1}  \pmod{\frac{n}{g}}  \Bigg] \Bigg\} \pmod{  \frac{mn}{g}}$$
I have already found the solution is given by 
$$x \equiv mq_0 + a \pmod{\frac{nm}{(m,n)}}$$
I can't move to that following from that equation to the one above it.

It seems to be some algebraic manipulation, however I can't find it.

Comment: Is g = gcd(m,n)?

Comment: yes  in this case gcd(m,n) = g

Comment: This cannot be correct, since without any hypothesis on the constants, a solution does not always exist. Of course neither does a modular inverse of $m/g$, but that is not an excuse for writing down a formula involving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x\equiv a\pmod{m} \implies x = mq+a \text{ for some } q\in \mathbb{Z}\tag{1}$

Plug this into second congruence 
$$\begin{align}mq+a&\equiv b\pmod{n}\\mq&\equiv b-a\pmod{n}\end{align}$$

Let $(m,n)=g$, and observe that the above linear congruence is solvable only if $g|(b-a)$
Divide $g$ through out and get
$$\begin{align} \frac{m}{g}q \equiv \frac{b-a}{g}\pmod{\frac{n}{g}}\end{align}$$

Next multiply both sides by the inverse of $\frac{m}{g}$ in modulo $\frac{n}{g}$
$$\begin{align} q &\equiv \frac{b-a}{g}\left(\frac{m}{g}\right)^{-1}\pmod{\frac{n}{g}}\\ \implies q&= \frac{b-a}{g}\left[\left(\frac{m}{g}\right)^{-1}\pmod{\frac{n}{g}}\right] + \frac{n}{g}k \end{align} $$

Plug this $q$ back into $(1)$ and you're done!